# filter datatable on loop

Tags: c#

Is there anyway of filtering datatable based on other datatable. something like below:

```
   foreach (datarow dr in somedatatable.select("id= someothertable.rows["someotherid"])
  {
     dr[somefield]=someothertable[someotherfield];
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do a ordinary `SQL` select using [DataView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.aspx)

```
DataView dv = new DataView(dataTableToFilter);
dv.RowFilter = ""//SQL condition
```

Complete useful example in your case you can find here:

[Creating a DataTable from a DataView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73kk32zz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Where you apply a `DataView` filter to a `DataTable` and create a new `DataTable` from filtered rows.

Comment: how is it possible to write sql condition based on some other datatable

Comment: first you apply SQL condition to *other* table, so you have filtered rows inside DataView of that table. After use that DataView to operate on another DataTable.

Comment: there is no property called filter

Comment: @arjun: as this is a FILTER, you need to apply a WHERE condition  **only**. For example: in your query you want all someid that is more then 100, so you write: dv.RowFilter = "someid>100";

Comment: How can I use multiple row in the statement like dv.Rowfilter= "someid =[multiplerows]"

Comment: @arjun: look in the link provided there is a complete code example.

Answer (score 0):

I have a question, why you want to do the filter logic in your code? Your example logic is very simple.

I order to do filter more efficient, we'd like use database to do that. I think your requirement can be implemented by using a join statement. Do you agree?